# Aggregate column which have same values

Tags: r

I'm working in R project. The table looks like this :

```
| x | o | o | x | 120
| x | x | x | o | 115
| o | o | o | x | 100
```

And another table :

```
| 1 | o | o | o | x |
| 2 | x | x | x | o |
| 3 | o | x | o | x |
| 4 | o | o | o | o |
```

My question is, how to combine it so :

```
| 1 | o | o | o | x | 100
| 2 | x | x | x | o | 115
```

It's ok if the first column isn't sorted. If the x o x o are same, it's joined. Any idea?

Comment: You can do a `merge` with the four columns and then do `aggregate` i.e. `df3 <- merge(df1, df2, by = names(df1)[1:4])` Regarding the aggregate part do you need to get the `sum`.  From the data, it is showing only a single row

Comment: Agree with @akrun. This is an inner join.